# How to add XML data to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to populate a dropdown list created in HTML with data i am matching from an XML file.

At the moment I can read the XML file and get the matching data i want using a javascript function and display the variable in an Alert window for debugging purposes.

However, I am unsure how to bind each piece of matching data to the dropdown list.

Below is the XML searching Function showing the alert popup and the variable "name", I want to display each entry of "name" as n option in the dropdownlist.

```
if (xmlDoc != null) {      
    var restaurants = new Array();
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Units");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "Container" ) {

           if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Allocated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "YES" ) {

            var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var telnumber = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Allocated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;               
                  alert("Found "+name); 
         }
       }
```

And here is my HTML dropDownlist populate with one "default" entry.

```
<select id="myDropDown" style="width: 95%; border-radius:8px; border:1px solid #AAAAAA;"><option value="default">Default</option></select>
```

Im just not sure how to get my "name" variable in there and populate a list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't this existing answer give you what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573407/populate-dropdown-from-xml-withtext-value  Or if you'd rather use pure JS (i.e., without jQuery), try this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-from-XML-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: Hi Marc, Thank you, that worked well!! I went for the pure JS method. Thanks